# How to set a specific brunch version in a project?

Tags: javascript, brunch

I want to set a specific brunch version in my project to avoid the compatibility errors when the others developers build the application.

Something like: Ruby version in the app Gemfile.

I tried this, but I don't know if this is the correct way

in the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "brunch": "1.7.13",
}
```

Comment: It is somewhat hard to understand what you want to achieve. Please consider editing your question to make sure you get valuable answers. Provide us with some details and try explaining your particular situation. Also why have you added the `brunch` tag but never mentioned brunch within qour question?

Answer (score 0):

Brunch is a build tool (like grunt), not a dependency manager like [bower](http://bower.io/).

I think you want to use [bower, in combination with brunch](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/stable/docs/faq.md#how-to-use-bower).

> - Make sure you have bower.json, which can be generated with `bower init`
> - Add packages to the dependencies field of your `bower.json`

To specify a specific version in bower, use for example:

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "1.11.1"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm using brunch + bower

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided IS the correct way to set a specific version of brunch for a project. Recent versions of brunch, when installed globally, will automatically defer to the version installed locally within a project.

So by specifying the version as a local dependency, all developers on the project will be using the same version of brunch regardless of which one is installed globally (as long as it's not a version that's way too outdated).

To avoid requiring developers to install brunch globally at all, you can also utilize the npm scripts feature. It will pick up the bin from the locally installed brunch. For example, in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "brunch watch --server",
    "build": "brunch build --production"
}
```

Which you would then have all the developers run with `npm run watch` or `npm run build`, respectively.